# Making field only editable when condition from other field is met using QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, mergin-maps

For a big field project I am using the app Input in which users can add points to a map. They have to provide some information about the objects (burial mounds). Input is wonderful for this, however I am unable to figure out one thing that many of the users are asking for.

The second field should only be prompted/able to be edited when in the first field the user has selected 'Yes' from a drop down menu. The problem right now is that this field is editable either way, which makes it unclear for some of the users.

Is it possible to enforce a field to only be editable when a certain condition from another field is met?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have no experience with Input app but a quick look at the [Input documentation](https://help.inputapp.io/) reveal that you can set default value, conditional visibility and constraint enforcement

So I think setting up a form with a conditional visibility for your second fiels should do the trick (the field will still be editable but will not be visible when it shouldn't be edited)  ([relevant documentation](https://help.inputapp.io/howto/settingup_forms_layout)), you could also add some more context for user by using alias for your field (for exemple going from "FIELD_2" to "Field two (fill only if field one is XXXX)")

Comment: That worked! Thanks.